# Getting the pitch/frequency of microphone audio in C#

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

Essentially, I'm trying to write a piece of software that can display the pitch of any incoming audio. I have a C# console app, and I'm using NAudio as a way to take in audio. Here's the code I have to do that:

```
int SampleRate = 44100;
int BufferMS = 1000;

NAudio.Wave.WaveInEvent Wave = new()
{
    DeviceNumber = 0,
    WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(SampleRate, 1),
    BufferMilliseconds = BufferMS
};

Wave.DataAvailable += OnWaveInData;
Wave.StartRecording();

void OnWaveInData(object? sender, NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs e)
{
    // get the frequency of the audio
    var freq = GetFrequency(e.Buffer, e.BytesRecorded);
    // print freq in hz
    Console.WriteLine($"\r{freq} Hz");
}
```

I used GitHub Copilot to help me write this next part, as I know I need to use some math to get a frequency out of this, but it seemed quite advanced.

```
double GetFrequency(byte[] buffer, int bytesRecorded)
{
    double max = 0;
    int maxN = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < bytesRecorded / 2; i++)
    {
        var real = buffer[2 * i];
        var imag = buffer[2 * i + 1];
        var magnitude = Math.Sqrt(real * real + imag * imag);
        if (magnitude > max)
        {
            max = magnitude;
            maxN = i;
        }
    }

    double freqN = maxN;
    if (maxN > 0 && maxN < bytesRecorded / 2 - 1)
    {
        var dL = buffer[2 * (maxN - 1)];
        var dR = buffer[2 * (maxN + 1)];
        freqN += 0.5 * (dR * dR - dL * dL) / (dR + dL - 2 * buffer[2 * maxN]);
    }

    return freqN * SampleRate / bytesRecorded;
}
```

It works somewhat okay, but the issue is the frequency reported can be quite sporadic and jump around which is not desireable. Should I just write a filter function to remove these "outliers", or am I approaching this completely incorrectly?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Looks like you're recording 16bit (2 byte) samples. No idea what your math is trying to do. (https://github.com/SjB/NAudio/blob/1a231399d117d1f4db69160295763d43868aff23/NAudio/Wave/WaveFormats/WaveFormat.cs#L43) You'll need to do some kind of fourier transform to extract frequency information from audio samples.

Comment: If you want the most prominent frequency you should probably do a FFT as Jermy suggest and pick the most prominent frequency from the spectogram. Note that if you want the momentary frequency you probably need to analyze a rolling buffer, and perhaps apply some windowing function to avoid artifacts at the edges. Consider asking in https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ for some suitable library.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented your procedure but I get some weird values like 218525442.36 in the freqN variable after the second block of calculations in the GetFrequency procedure.
It is from the variables dL and dr that values of the type 1 560 501 425 are returned to me and I don't understand why
You have suggestions
Thank you
Mimmo

Comment: I'll be completely honest, I found it was much easier to do this in Java, so I switched my project over. Once I get a fully working solution, I'll be sure to post it in at least Java (and hopefully C#)!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @SprintKeyz Did you get this working in Java?

Comment: @WilliamJohnHolden sadly I wasn't able to since I don't fully understand the math. I've been quite busy, but hopefully I'll be able to revisit this once I have time to take a deeper dive and look at other people's implementations!